# Patching Touching Databases

Tags: sharepoint-server, patching

I have a disaster recovery farm that is mirrored to my production farm. We are way behind in patching so it will take a while to patch all the servers in my production farm. In the meantime I have to de-couple the DR farm from mirroring. The SQL Server fellow tells me he has to copy all the databases over again to mirror the two SQL Server instances again which puts the DR farm offline for a few days until he can get that done. I am trying o avoid this so I am wondering if the patches (May 2017) change the databases(s) and how to tell?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to properly tell is to build a mirror of your farm’s configuration (probably just a single server but with the same services running would be sufficient): right down to the same patch level.

Make note of the patch version in the databases.

Patch the farm to the level required and make note of the changes to the version table in the databases, if any.

The patch documentation never mentions if there will be a schema change, or an increase in the min required schema version.